# Prevent mpv's progress bar from covering video

Tags: video-player, mpv-media-player

I have managed to set mpv's progress bar as always visible by adding `visibility=always` to `~/.config/mpv/script-opts/osc.conf`. However, the bar occludes part of the video.

Is there a way to resize the video area so that it is not covered by the bar (like in VLC)?

I have found `--window-scale`, `--autofit` and its variants in the manual, but none of them solved my problem, they only change the window size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The option you are looking for is [`boxvideo`](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#on-screen-controller-boxvideo), which is available for mpv 0.31 and above (see relevant [git commit](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/commit/971dbcc21cc1468c23bf37bb6fcc42a7c7797300)). Just add:

```
boxvideo=yes
```

in your `~/.config/mpv/script-opts/osc.conf` and your video should be displayed above the progress bar.

Also make sure to change the vertical position of the subtitles, because they will be probably covered from the OSC now, by adding the [`sub-margin-y`](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#options-sub-margin-y) option in your `~/.config/mpv/mpv.conf` file as:

```
sub-margin-y=<size>
```

where `<size>` represents the top and bottom screen margin for the subs in scaled pixels.

---

To install the latest version of mpv, if it isn't included in the default repositories of your Ubuntu version, you can add [mpv's PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Emc3man/+archive/ubuntu/mpv-tests) by running the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/mpv-tests
sudo apt-get update
```

Then reinstall mpv:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall mpv
```